# Windows Server 2012 64 bit is not working

Tags: windows-xp, installation, windows-server-2012, boot

I have Windows Server 2012 enterprise edition bootable disk. When I am restarting my system I am not getting an option of bootable disk. As I have already have Windows XP installed in my system so when I am trying to run the setup file from there it is giving me an error that

> The application is of 64 bit which can not run on 32 bit

Now, I want to know that what does this message means?
Does it mean that my Machine (PC) is 32 bit and I can only install OS which is of 32 bit or it is my Windows XP who is stopping me to install 64 bit OS?

Here is my system information

[image]

Comment: try asking this on SuperUser SE.

Comment: @mdpc Thanks but I am not feeling to write my question anywhere in SO. I am bit disappointed with the kind of response I got from the so well respected developers community ! Thanks again though for your input

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite Your question is frankly pretty bad. [As other people mentioned, you're leaving out any details that would help us](http://serverfault.com/questions/515320/windows-server-2012-64-bit-is-not-working#comment583535_515335). Feel free to edit this question if you would like to try to get better answers (for starters, tell us what kind of computer this is - a screenshot of some random tool doesn't help much). Note that if your system is so old that it is not supported by Server 2012 the only answer you'll get here is "You need to use supported hardware".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the boot option in the motherboard's BIOS to boot from the installation media. If the boot fails then the media is corrupt or at least the boot record is incorrect on it.

Comment: +1 for suggestion. I changed boot option but nothing happened. I also tried to install iso via VMware but I am getting the same 64 bit error

Comment: sorry, where does vmware come into the equation?

Comment: @Chooper3 I don't know why you just want to humiliate my every comment but I said this just because meanwhile I was trying to look upon other opportunities to install it. That's why I said "I also tried". If you think my question is not good enough please vote to close but don't discourage me :(

Comment: I've not downvoted you at all, and I'm not remotely interested in humilating you, but I am finding it very hard trying to drag out of you the actual facts of what you have and what you're trying to do - so for you to suddenly mention vmware blurs the issue considerably - you mention it without any context, so we don't know what you're doing. You can help yourself by adding extra detail, look in the FAQ if you need help, I'm keen to help you but it all seems like 'smoke and mirrors' right now, you're inadvertedly hiding information that may help

Comment: Wmare is a company, not a product. Chopper3 keeps asking you to *tell us more details.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed booting directly into the disc, then yes, the XP machine is likely ancient and thus does not have a 64 bit processor. hard to believe though. Would be REALLY old.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does that means I need to have Windows Server 2012 32 bit edition ?

Comment: You mean the one that is not supported for production use? What about checking your hardware and getting something that was not made when most young admins where still in base school? We really talk of ANCIENT - I have 6 year old machines here and they are all 64 bit.

Comment: But I had Windows Server 2003 installed in my system previously. But this link says Windows Server is only for 64 bit machine. Which does indicate that my machine is 64 bit. I am confuse now ! http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsserver2008r2general/thread/4d9d6f93-974b-4f93-b7cb-4394d0ed4e96

Comment: I have just installed this software https://www.grc.com/securable.htm and it says that 64 bit processing available

Comment: By the way, I bought my PC in 2005 :)

Comment: Vote to close, offtopic here - not professional capacity, that is a superuser.com question. And STOP LYING. See, you say you bought the PC in 2005. That is nice. You also tell us the PC has an Intel E7500. Not at http://ark.intel.com/products/36503/ you can read: Launch Date - Q1'09. How did you buy a PC in 2005 with a CPU that was released in 2009?

Comment: I am sorry if my question hurt you that much.. but I am in serious problem. Thanks anyways for investing your time on searching processor version. I appreciate your assistance. Feel free to close it :)

Comment: Windows Server 2003 could run on 32-bit OR 64-bit. Starting with Windows Server 2008 R2, it's 64-bit only.

Comment: Why is this a serious problem, you can't be serious about running a brand new, and very expensive version, of OS on a very old currently-XP-based system - it seems like you're not approaching this particularly seriously. If you are then you need to give us MUCH more information, as much as you can in fact, not just a paragraph.

Comment: +1 @NathanC .. at least I am able to resolve one mystery :) .. but now my system support 64 bit.. is there any possibility I can install it without uninstalling Windows XP.  One more thing I remember that I first installed Windows Server 2003 and after that I installed Windows XP on another drive.. Can that be the reason I am not able to switch to 64 bit again ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite the issue is that you don't seem to be able to boot the CD/DVD - you're NEVER going to be able to run a 64-bit installer application on a 32-bit OS, you NEED to boot the disc. Now you haven't told us anything about the actual server but there's a pretty good chance the boot order is configurable in the BIOS/EUFI, if you let us know the make/model of machine we may be able to help further.

Comment: @TomTom I know it is needless to argue upon as I need to first focus upon my problem first but fortunately I did upgrade my system hard disk and RAM somewhere between the period. And I am not LYING :)

Comment: You have to install 2012 OVER the XP installation. They won't work side-by-side. Why would you want XP anyway?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite - maybe not lying but something's not right, you EITHER got the machine in 2005 OR it's not got an E7500 - one or the other

Comment: @NathanC - he suddenly introduces the word 'vmware' out of the air in a comment up there, either he doesn't know what he's doing or he doesn't want to tell us something.

Comment: I am sorry for all the trouble. you can close the question. It is just I am pretty weak in hardware and software installation side and I thought somehow I will be able to get some help from here. Thanks anyways for your response and time. Please let me know if you want me to except your response as a answer to your question.